# API Reporte sheets

Tags: api, rest, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy usando una API para realizar reportes, que me genere en un sheet la lista de usuarios Uso Gmail, Uso Drive, Uso Fotos, Cuota Usada, Cuota Total y este es el codigo que tengo:

```
function UsoCuota(){
  var today = new Date();
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  Logger.log(oneWeekAgo);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  
  var parameters = [
    'accounts:last_login_time',
    'gmail:num_emails_received',
    'docs:num_docs',
    'accounts:gmail_used_quota_in_mb',
    'accounts:drive_used_quota_in_mb',
    'accounts:gplus_photos_used_quota_in_mb',
    'accounts:used_quota_in_mb',
    'accounts:total_quota_in_mb',
    'accounts:used_quota_in_percentage'
  ];
   var rows = [];
  var link = "";
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date, {
      parameters: parameters.join(','),
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var reports = page.usageReports;
    if (reports) {
      
      for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        var report = reports[i];
        var parameterValues = getParameterValues(report.parameters);
       // Logger.log(i);
        var total;
        Logger.log("1:"+parameterValues['accounts:total_quota_in_mb']);
        if(parameterValues['accounts:total_quota_in_mb'] == -1){
          total = 'unlimited';
        }else{
          total =parameterValues['accounts:total_quota_in_mb'];
        }
        link = addLinkChartPie('Repport for '+report.entity.userEmail,parameterValues['accounts:total_quota_in_mb'],parameterValues['accounts:gmail_used_quota_in_mb'],parameterValues['accounts:drive_used_quota_in_mb'],parameterValues['accounts:gplus_photos_used_quota_in_mb']);
        var row = [
          
          report.entity.userEmail,
          parameterValues['docs:num_docs'],
          parameterValues['gmail:num_emails_received'],
          parameterValues['accounts:gmail_used_quota_in_mb'],
          parameterValues['accounts:drive_used_quota_in_mb'],
          parameterValues['accounts:gplus_photos_used_quota_in_mb'],
          parameterValues['accounts:used_quota_in_mb'],
          total,
          parameterValues['accounts:used_quota_in_percentage']+'%',
          link
        ];
        
        Logger.log(row);
        rows.push(row);
        var u = i+2;
        Logger.log(u);
        var strRange = 'D'+ u +':G'+u;
        
      }
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  if (rows.length > 0) {
    //var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Google Apps User Usage Report');
    var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    
    var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Cuotas");
   
    deleteData(sheet);

    // Append the headers.
   //    var headers = ['Date', 'User', 'Last Login', 'Num Emails Received',
   //        'Num Docs'];
   //    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 10).setValues(rows);
    

    //  Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No results returned.');
  }
}
function getParameterValues(parameters) {
  return parameters.reduce(function(result, parameter) {
    var name = parameter.name;
    var value;
    if (parameter.intValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.intValue;
    } else if (parameter.stringValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.stringValue;
    } else if (parameter.datetimeValue !== undefined) {
      value = new Date(parameter.datetimeValue);
    } else if (parameter.boolValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.boolValue;
    }
    result[name] = value;
    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

Este es el problema que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Servicios activados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que no está detectando la API y no encuentro el manual de está API, no está dentro de los servicios donde se añade la api, si me pueden recomendar otra API que me realice este reporte se los agradecería o si me ayudan solucionando el error, tiene todos los permisos de la G suite para extraer estos datos de Google Workspace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logré solucionar la parte del error del "get" y ahora ya me detecta la API, hice los pasos según me señalaste lo que debía corregir, me quedó este problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Clarifica tu problema. Al hablar de *una* API, o de *esta* API, sin indicar a qué te refieres, con enlaces incluidos, será complicado ayudarte. ¿Te refieres a la [API de Admin SDK Reports](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports?hl=es-419)? Explica qué has añadido en Apps Script, en la parte de la izquierda (muestra una captura de pantalla si es posible) y dinos si estamos hablando de Google Workspace. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta, faltan varios detalles importantes.

Comment: Si me refiero a esa API, y ya añado la captura de imagen de la parte izquierda, y si estamos hablando de Google Workspace

Comment: He probado este mismo código y me funciona a la perfección. ¿Qué aparece si seleccionas el apartado `Información general`, primera opción del menú de la izquierda?

Comment: ¿Me podrías indicar como añadiste la API?, osea como que nombre le añadiste en servicio o como lo añadiste en servicio, tal vez puede que el que tenga "AdminReports" no sea el adecuado, me pasó con otra API igual, pero tenian la misma función.

Comment: Dame un segundo, porque lo probé sobre un script en el que tengo otras APIs, voy a crear uno nuevo con sólo esto y ahora te muestro.

Comment: Y en la parte de información general creo que quieres visualizar esta parte supondré, me indica esto:   ` https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.licensing
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

Comment: Y, ¿qué se supone que es`addLinkChartPie` exactamente? ¿Es  una función? ¿Dónde la has definido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La API que tienes que agregar, pulsando en `Servicios +` es la siguiente: **`Admin SDK API`** y en `Versión` tienes que elegir **`reports_v1`**.

Luego, y MUY IMPORTANTE, presta atención al `Identificador` que darás al servicio, porque deberás usar ese mismo Identificador en el código:

```
AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date, {
```

Ese puede ser el motivo de tu error, porque quizá en `AdminReports` hayas definido otra cosa, por ejemplo, hayas elegido `directory_v1` en vez de `reports_v1`.

Finalmente, no olvide pulsar en `Añadir`.

Te dejo una captura de pantalla, en mi caso, me ponía por defecto `AdminDirectory` y he cambiado el identificador por `AdminReports`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo esto, el código funciona en mi caso:

Puse esto antes del `return` de `getParameterValues()`:

```
Logger.log(value);
```

Y puedo ver los valores:

```
16:38:45    Información 145
16:38:45    Información 6125
16:38:45    Información 5
16:38:45    Información 6276
16:38:45    Información 30720
16:38:45    Información 20
16:38:45    Información 0
16:38:45    Información 1:30720
```

Comment: Perfecto, logré que me detectará la API, me quedo el error mencionado anteriormente